# I passed a prop "function" to a child component => Error props is undefined

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to ReactJs and I'm trying to pass a function to my child component that updates a state in the parent component!

It seems like the child component can't find the passed function.

The errors message I'm receiving when I click: 
TypeError: this.props.cencelLogin is not a function

Another one when I access child component "this is a console error that doesn't crash the program":
Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.

I console.log(this.props) = I can't find any evidence that getBackCancelLoginForm is exists. "I'm new to this"

I watched a few videos of components communication. It seems that this technique is working; however, this technique is not working for me because of a minor mistake.

this is my parent class component:

```
class Menu extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      show: 'Defualt'
    };

    this.getBackCancelLoginForm = this.getBackCancelLoginForm.bind(this);
  }

  getBackCancelLoginForm = (showVal) => {
    this.setState({ show: showVal });
  }

  render() {

    this.CheckShowMenu();

    return (
      <div>

        { this.state.show === "Defualt" ? <DefualtMenu  cencelLogin={this.getBackCancelLoginForm}/> : (<div> </div>)}

      </div>

    );
  }
}
```

this is my child class component:

```
class loginCom extends Component {
    constructor(props){
      super();

      this.state = {
        cancelSignIn: "Defualt",
      };

      this.cancel = this.cancel.bind(this);
    }

    cancel(props){
      this.props.cencelLogin(this.state.cancelSignIn);
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <div>

        <div className="headerCancelBox" onClick={this.cancel.bind(this)}>

        </div>
      );
    }
}
```

In the actual result: the sing in form should desperate.

when clicking 'X' on the child component -> the function cancel should fire which call the prop function.
which cause child function to be replaced with another child function "Default Menu"

Answer (score 0):

I find my silly mistake! I have to admit that I spend hrs on solving this.

I will leave the answer here forever get the same issue!

I just passed the prop to the wrong child function. :)